# Adding a string array to a list

Tags: java, list, arrays

For the `add()` method how do I add a string array to a list of string arrays?
E.g:

```
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] myString = {"foo", "bar"};
myList.add(new String[](myString)); //does not work
```

EDIT: yes I have tried `myList.add(myString)` however, only want the value of myString not pass by reference.

Comment: i guess `myList.add(myString)` will do your job.

Comment: Edited my post to clarify.

Comment: @meiryo I added an answer without explictly creating a new variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Updated answer

In response to this

> EDIT: yes I have tried myList.add(myString) however, only want the
>   value of myString not pass by reference.

```
String[] newArr = new String[myString.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length; i ++) {
    newArr[i] = myString[i];
}
myList.add(newArr);
```

And this

> Thanks for an updated answer. Is it the only solution though? Feels a little weird that Java doesn't have a shorter solution and having to create another variable just to do it. – meiryo

```
String[] newArr = new String[myString.length];
System.arraycopy(myString, 0, newArr, 0, myString.length);
```

---

### (Old answer)

```
myList.add(new String[](myString)); //does not work    
myList.add(myString); //works
```

Why are you using `new String[]`?

Note: If you want to dynamically generate an array, this will do:

```
myList.add(new String[] {"string1", "string2", "foo", "bar"});
```

Therefore your example could be shortened to this:

```
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
myList.add(new String[] {"foo", "bar"});
```

Comment: Thanks for an updated answer. Is it the only solution though? Feels a little weird that Java doesn't have a shorter solution and having to create another variable just to do it.

Comment: @meiryo Re-updated answer, but yes you have to create a new variable.

Comment: @Doorknob nice answer. But you don't have to explicitly create a new variable. See my answer.

Comment: @jlordo Hm. I never knew that. :P

Answer (score 2):

This answer came after the edit to your post. You don't have to explicitly create another variable, use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[] original, int newlength)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29).

So you can simply write:

```
myList.add(Arrays.copyOf(myString, myString.length));
```

Comment: Oh that's convenient. :D +1

Comment: After using this I'm still getting a reference value `[[Ljava.lang.String;@18987a33]` for myList instead of the content value. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean you get a reference value? you mean in `System.out.println(something);`? Show us the relevant code. My answer creates a new array, copies in the Strings of the original one and adds that array to your list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] myString = {"foo", "bar"};
myList.add(myString);
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

did you already try myList.add(myString) ;